# Fastest way to check the numerical value of a boxed primitive integral type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, equality, primitive

I need to write a method with the following semantics:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if <paramref name="x"/> is a boxed instance of a primitive integral type
/// whose numerical value equals to <paramref name="y"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">An object reference. Can be <c>null</c>.</param>
/// <param name="y">A numerical value of type <see cref="ulong"/> to compare with.</param>
/// <returns>
/// <c>true</c> if <paramref name="x"/> refers to a boxed instance of type 
/// <see cref="sbyte"/>, <see cref="short"/>, <see cref="int"/>, <see cref="long"/>, 
/// <see cref="byte"/>, <see cref="ushort"/>, <see cref="uint"/>, or <see cref="ulong"/>, 
/// whose numerical value equals to the numerical value of <paramref name="y"/>; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </returns>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// This method checks only for numeric equality, even if its arguments are of different runtime types
/// (e.g. <c>2L</c> is considered to be equal to <c>2UL</c>).
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// This method returns <c>false</c> if <paramref name="x"/> is <c>null</c>
/// or refers to an instance of a reference type or a boxed instance of a value type except
/// the primitive integral types listed above (e.g. it returns <c>false</c> if <paramref name="x"/>
/// refers to a boxed instance of an <c>enum</c> type, <see cref="bool"/>, <see cref="char"/>, <see cref="IntPtr"/>,
/// <see cref="UIntPtr"/>, <see cref="float"/>, <see cref="double"/>, <see cref="decimal"/>, or <see cref="BigInteger"/>).
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// This method should not throw any exceptions, or cause any observable side-effects
/// (e.g. invoke a method that could modify the state of an object referenced by <paramref name="x"/>). 
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
[Pure]
public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y)
```

The implementation should be as fast as possible (assuming there is no expected bias in input data towards certain types or values of the parameter `x`), and should not use `unsafe` code or P/Invoke. Of course, among fastest implementations, I would prefer one that is simplest and shortest.

My solution is as follows:

```
public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y)
{
    if (x is sbyte)
    {
        sbyte z = (sbyte)x;
        return z >= 0 && y == (ulong)z;
    }

    if (x is short)
    {
        short z = (short)x;
        return z >= 0 && y == (ulong)z;
    }

    if (x is int)
    {
        int z = (int)x;
        return z >= 0 && y == (ulong)z;
    }

    if (x is long)
    {
        long z = (long)x;
        return z >= 0 && y == (ulong)z;
    }

    if (x is byte)
    {
        return y == (byte)x;
    }

    if (x is ushort)
    {
        return y == (ushort)x;
    }

    if (x is uint)
    {
        return y == (uint)x;
    }

    if (x is ulong)
    {
        return y == (ulong)x;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it already contains a  working solution.  To request a critique of a working solution consider asking on Code Review.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to make this any faster is to eliminate the boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Why not make 10 different overloads? It will keep you from having to do 10 `if` checks and with a little template you don't have to copy paste it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: How would you implement the overload resolution, if you're always accepting an `object` and a `ulong`?

Comment: I'm not really strong in this but couldn't you use some bitwise operators? (Here, half of a maybee working solution, I'm a genius huehuehue)

Comment: @TopinFrassi: You'd still have to unbox it first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `NumericalEquals(byte, ulong)`, `NumericalEquals(int, ulong)`, etc with a fallback `NumericalEquals(object, ulong)`. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Serve The requirement is to produce the fastest code solving the problem. It's not immediately obvious that my solution satisfies this requriement, so it might be not "working".

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: You would still need a case statement to get the object into the proper type before passing it, so you're just pushing the complexity somewhere else.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The input data is already in the boxed form, so overloads whould not help as they work only at compile-time (unless one uses `dynamic` type, but it is too slow for the given task).

Comment: @gunr2171 The code performance can be measured objectively, so it does not seem very opinionated.

Comment: Can you type out the actual requirements? Humans aren't that good at parsing XML.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: perhaps you can tell me if I am making a mistake in my tests but [I see](https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/2bf4a27d8b8777b34b82) a consistent 16xxms vs 42xxms when using method overloading instead of `if`-statements (including when I switch the execution order). Compiler optimization shaves 1/4th of each execution time: 12xx vs 31xx.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: It doesn't look like you've accounted for the time it takes to unbox the `object`.  You might want to check and see if all of those overloads are actually being called.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: both approaches use same `object` array and overload resolution will make sure I only call one of the overloads so I don't see how that would be any different between my scenario and the one with multiple `if`. Where would I have to account for that unboxing?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Are you sure all those overloads actually being called?  Or only the one containing an `object` parameter?  Your code does not check the returned results to see if they are actually correct.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I think if you look carefully, you will see that the only overload your code is calling is 

`public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y) { return false; }`, which *does not require unboxing.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: disregard my last comment, that was a totally wrong conclusion. You're right, it does only call the `object` overload. My hunch was wrong.

Comment: How about `public static bool NumericalEquals<T>(T x, ulong y)` ?

Comment: @Magnus You would need to rewrite cast operators as `(int)(object)x` and you still end up with boxing (I believe JIT does not eliminate it in this case).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov No I dont think so `(int)x` should do and no boxing.

Answer (score 2):

Since each of the integer primitive types is sealed, the `is` operations performed by your reference implementation are compiled by the JIT to simply an equality comparison between the `RuntimeTypeHandle` of the type of the object `x` (likely obtained through either one or two pointer dereferences) and the handle of a particular integer type (likely implemented as an inline literal or a single `mov` instruction that references a fixed memory location). It would be difficult, if not impossible, to improve upon the initial implementation without leveraging information about the distribution of the inputs to the method.

Comment: Why on Earth are you posting multiple answers to the same question?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the performances but it is shorter:

```
public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y)
{
    var unsigned = (x as byte?) ?? (x as ushort?) ?? (x as uint?) ?? (x as ulong?);
    if (unsigned.HasValue)
    {
        return (unsigned.Value == y);
    }

    var signed = (x as sbyte?) ?? (x as short?) ?? (x as int?) ?? (x as long?);
    return (signed.HasValue) && (signed.Value >= 0) && ((ulong) signed.Value == y);
}
```

In worst cases, there will be 3 cast (like `object` to `sbyte?` to `long?` then the value to `ulong`), and I don't talk about the `Nullable<T>` <s>ab</s>use, so it's probably slowest than your solution.

**[edit]**

I forget that there is a bonus : no `is` tests. Your worst case is 1 `is` and 2 cast. So maybe the performances can be good enough.

**[edit 2]**

Also you may consider a fast elimination test to improve average cost:

```
public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y)
{
    if (x.GetHashCode() != y.GetHashCode()) return false;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Under the constraints of your original question, the alternative to your current implementation which I would definitely test is the following. Depending on the implementation of [`Type.GetTypeCodeImpl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecodeimpl.aspx) used by the .NET Framework classes representing primitive types, this operation could prove faster by replacing up to 5 type checks with a `switch` on the result of 2 virtual calls (plus one to handle enums). It uses the fact that the [`TypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx) enumeration contains members for each of the primitive integral types.

```
public static bool NumericalEquals(object x, ulong y)
{
  if (x == null)
    return false;

  Type type = x.GetType();
  if (type.IsEnum)
    return false;

  switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
  {
  case TypeCode.Byte:
    return (byte)x == y;

  ...other cases here

  default:
    return false;
  }
}
```

You could avoid the call to `IsEnum` by wrapping the block in a `try`/`catch` to handle the exception that would only be thrown when a boxed enum is provided as input. That might improve performance of the expected cases at the slight expense of a slower `false` result for boxed enums.

Comment: This wouldn't be any different than the OP's code.

Comment: This does not work correctly for enums, and is slower than my initial solution.

Comment: @Servy It avoids 5 type checks if the input is a `ushort`, in favor of 2 virtual calls.

Comment: @280Z28 But that's just it, it *doesn't* avoid those 5 types checks.  They're still going to be there.

Comment: @Servy I updated my answer. The runtime *could*, but is not required to, implement `Type.GetTypeCodeImpl` in a manner that does not result in those type checks. According to the information provided by Vladimir, the current implementation is not optimized for this case, and does not prove faster than the original code.

Comment: This assumes that the call to `GetType` and `GetTypeCode` is in fact faster than doing an `is`. There is nothing documented to say either way, which makes me wary of saying A or B. I naively think it will be, since I don't see how doing an `is` operation can do worse than checking the type, over and over again (in this case), but I would definitely love some hard data on this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please see my updated introduction to the answer.

Comment: @280Z28 I would like to note that I know of no faster way to do this. But a question that involves "fastest" and the concept of an unknown type in the same context is always going to be a bit odd in my opinion. I, myself, was a bit perplexed by the concept of the speed of a non-rectangular array in .NET being (slightly) faster than a rectangular one, due to the way the code is actually compiled, and why (usage statistics), so any code that seems to care about "any type" or "unknown type" and at the same time speed, seems bogus to me. I'M NOT GOING TO TELL YOU, JUST DO IT AS FAST AS POSSIBLE!

Comment: @280Z28 `try / catch` would not work, because boxed enums can be successfully unboxed to their underlying integral types (this is not documented in C# spec).